# How to copy folder permissions to a new, different domain?

Tags: windows, active-directory, permissions, domain

We have to change our domain due to a corporate mandate, we can't to it all at once because of this, that, and the other thing.

We need users on both domains to be able to access our network shares.
Is there a way to mirror file permissions from one domain for the new domain?

For example:

The domain **Nebraska** has a share called **Public**, members of the group **Nebraska/PublicUsers** have full rights. 
The new domain **America** has access to that share as well, I want members of **America/PublicUsers** to have full rights too.

Is there a tool that will look in the share **Public**, find **Nebraska\PublicUsers**, then ADD **America\PublicUsers** to that folder based on a *\xyz search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free SetACL can do exactly what you want. [**Have a look at this example**](http://helgeklein.com/setacl/examples/managing-file-system-permissions-with-setacl-exe/#example-5-migrating-permissions-between-domains)

In the example, users/groups from Domain A are replaced with corresponding users/groups from Domain B, but SetACL can copy permissions from Domain A to Domain B just as well. Just change "da:repldom" to "da:cpydom". See the [documentation](http://helgeklein.com/setacl/documentation/command-line-version-setacl-exe/#domainaction) for details.